# MAE using Pipeline and GridSearchCV

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am facing a challenge finding Mean Average Error (MAE) using Pipeline and GridSearchCV

**Background:**

I have worked on a Data Science project (MWE as below) where a MAE value would be returned of a classifier as it's performance metric.

```
#Library
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

#Data import and preparation
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data_features = ['location','event_type_count','log_feature_count','total_volume','resource_type_count','severity_type']
X = data[data_features]
y = data.fault_severity

#Train Validation Split for Cross Validation
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

#RandomForest Modeling
RF_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
RF_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

#RandomForest Prediction
y_predict = RF_model.predict(X_valid)

#MAE 
print(mean_absolute_error(y_valid, y_predict))
#Output:
#   0.38727149627623564
```

**Challenge:**

Now I am trying to implement the same using Pipeline and GridSearchCV (MWE as below). The expectation is the same MAE value would be returned as above. Unfortunately I could not get it right using the 3 approaches below.

```
#Library
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

#Data import and preparation
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
data_features = ['location','event_type_count','log_feature_count','total_volume','resource_type_count','severity_type']
X = data[data_features]
y = data.fault_severity

#Train Validation Split for Cross Validation
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

#RandomForest Modeling via Pipeline and Hyper-parameter tuning
steps = [('rf', RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0))]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps) # define the pipeline object.
parameters = {'rf__n_estimators':[100]}
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=None, refit=True)
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Approach 1:
print(grid.best_score_)
# Output:
#    -0.508130081300813

#Approach 2:
y_predict=grid.predict(X_valid)
print("score = %3.2f"%(grid.score(y_predict, y_valid)))
# Output:
#    ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
#    array=[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1. 0.].
#    Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

#Approach 3:
y_predict_df = pd.DataFrame(y_predict.reshape(len(y_predict), -1),columns=['fault_severity'])
print("score = %3.2f"%(grid.score(y_predict_df, y_valid)))
# Output: 
#    ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 6 and input n_features is 1
```

**Discussion:**

Approach 1:
  As in `GridSearchCV()` the `scoring` variable is set to `neg_mean_squared_error`, tried to read the `grid.best_score_`. But it did not get the same MAE result.

Approach 2:
  Tried to get the `y_predict` values using `grid.predict(X_valid)`. Then tried to get the MAE using `grid.score(y_predict, y_valid)` as the `scoring` variable in `GridSearchCV()` is set to `neg_mean_squared_error`. It returned a `ValueError` complaining "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead".

Approach 3:
  Tried to reshape `y_predict` and it did not work either. This time it returned "ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input."

It would be helpful if you can assist to point where I could have made the error?

If you need, the data.csv is available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/t1h53jg1hy4x33b/data.csv

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare `mean_absolute_error` with `neg_mean_squared_error` which is very different refer [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter) for more details. You should have used `neg_mean_absolute_error` in your `GridSearchCV` object creation like shown below:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters,scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=None, refit=True)
```

Also, the [score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.score) method in sklearn takes `(X,y)` as inputs, where `x` is your input feature of shape `(n_samples, n_features)` and `y` is the target labels, you need to change your `grid.score(y_predict, y_valid)` into `grid.score(X_valid, y_valid)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did the errors which you have pointed. Understand it better now. The below is the value I got with Pipeline and GridSearchCV, this value is exactly the same as the solution I had without the Pipeline and GridSearchCV.

print("score = %3.17f"%(grid.score(X_valid, y_valid)))
#-0.38727149627623564

Comment: One more doubt.The grid.score() method returns -0.38727149627623564 while the grid.best_score_ attribute returns -0.3871951219512195. Found grid.best_score_ gives better value for the scoring parameter. Understand the best_score_ uses the average value of all CV folds using the best_estimator_. How different is the score method in calculating its value? Shouldn't it use the best_estimator_ too as grid object via GridSearchCV had tuned its hyperparameter? In MWE, I used only 1 value for n_estimators, hence expected the same value for both grid.score() method and grid.best_score_ attribute.

Comment: you are applying `grid.score()` on `X_valid` and `y_valid` but in grid search you are not using the cross validation data as `X_valid` and `y_valid` so you are testing them on two different data sets, due to which the results are different.

Comment: Got it, 
 grid.score() -  used the validation set data,
 grid.best_score_ - used the training set data.
Hence different results. Learnt much from you. Thanks for your patience.